# Show table rownumber

Tags: jquery-templates

I have a script which type is="text/x-tmpl"

This script generates the rows and columns into the tbody.

What I try to do is to create a column which have a input to show the number of row of each item.

example:

row 1: thumbnail - Filename - 1

row 2: thumbnail - Filenaem - 2

...

...

I want that the user can change his row number.

The problem is that always show "0".

Here is the code:

```
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td><input type="text" value="{%=[i]%}"></td> /**My input to show the number of row**/
   </tr>   
{% } %}
```

Comment: Take the square brackets off the `i` in `{%=[i]%}`?

Comment: @gvee: i have test it , but when i remove the brackets the value are empty

Comment: More information required then bud. Can you knock up a jsfiddle?

Comment: a fiddle its difficult. because requires a lot of script to make this working. Here is a link what plugin im using, its a demo (blueimp jquery file upload)  http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html